# How to read headers in kafka partitioner

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'd like to extend Kafka DefaultPartitioner to make a custom one. However, I find no way to access the message headers as the partitioning should be based on a value present there.

**EDIT 1:** The task is choosing a partition not based on the key but on another integer contained in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access headers in custom partitioner class. But maybe you can create ProducerRecord manually on basis of your header value.

ProducerRecord has many overloaded constructor definitions. Some of them have partition argument. There you can specify partition number which says in which partition your ProducerRecord will go.

e.g
`ProducerRecord<String,String> rec = new ProducerRecord(topic, partitionNo, key, value);`

Otherwise you will have to embed that specific header value inside key or value object and then access it inside partitioner class.

Comment: For frameworks where ProducerRecord constructor cannot be modified, a `ProducerInterceptor` interface can also inject/override header information

Comment: I tried ProducerInterceptor. But there only key and value objects are injected. I could not see headers there.

Comment: Should be able to use `return new ProducerRecord(..., headers)`

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm not sure I'm following this conversation. Could you elaborate further and provide sample implementations?

Comment: @OneCricketeer The task is choosing a partition not based on the key but on another integer contained in the header. If I implement a ProducerInterceptor, I can use Reflection to modify the partition based on the header, but this is super dirty. Other ideas?

Comment: @Cap If you have direct access to the ProducerRecord constructor, just parse the data you're about to send, and set up partition/header information there. Otherwise, if you have no control over the producer (e.g  it's embedded in some other framework/library), then that library should be able to set any random producer properties, where an interceptor could be introduced. You shouldn't need reflection. The `ProducerRecord.key()` method is public and you would return a new record, not modify the input parameter with reflection

Comment: @OneCricketeer Regarding your first option, are you proposing to call the send method specifying the partition directly there? Or are you proposing to do this by extending KafkaTemplate? It's very difficult to understand without examples. Regarding the second option, this is not feasable because the key is not used to choose the partition, as I said. We need to use a value in the header.

Comment: @OneCricketeer or maybe you're proposing to implement a producer interceptor and return always a copy of that record where only the partition is changed?

Comment: @Cap No answer here is referring to Spring. The answer here is suggesting the first option you mentioned. My comment was saying if that's not possible, then an interceptor could be used, which, yes, returns a new instance of record, using whatever ProducerRecord constructor you want that includes the partition/header information